# addClass 'selected' to a link that match page title

Tags: jquery, addclass

I am trying to set up a navigation using wordpress and I have difficulty to pass the 'selected' class that matches the page title to a link that wp has generated for me. How do I refer to a specific `$(this)` link and add the class?

```
<div class="container menu_nav">
    <ul class="grid_12">
        <?php
            $args = array('menu' => 'main-menu', 'echo' => false);
            $navMenu = wp_nav_menu($args);
            $pageTitle = get_the_title();
            echo '<span id="page_title">'.$pageTitle.'</span>';
            $stripTags = strip_tags($navMenu, '<li><a>');
            echo $stripTags;
        ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var nav = '.menu_nav ul li a';
    var linkTitle = $(nav).attr('title');
    var arr = [];
    var pageTitle = document.getElementById('page_title');
    var pageAttr = pageTitle.innerHTML;
    var linkClass = document.getElementsByClassName("menu-item");

    $(nav).each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).text())
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i] == pageAttr) {
            $(linkClass).addClass('selected');
        } else {
            $(linkClass).removeClass('selected');
        }
    }
    console.log(arr.join());
    console.log(linkTitle,pageAttr);
});
```

Comment: Please clarify your problem. It's not clear

Comment: Hi, Rory, if you check the for loop right now I am passing addClass and removeClass to every link of the navigation when it finds the page title that matches the link title. How do I addClass and removeClass in a specific li item and not all the li items at the same time. I've also changed my array that now it gets all the a links titles in it :                            $(nav).each(function() {
   arr.push($(this).attr('title'));
 });

Answer (score 1):

You will have to do that in a single loop

```
$(nav).each(function() {
         arr.push($(this).text()) ;
         if ($(this).text() == pageAttr) {
                 $(this).addCass('selected');
            }
});
```

Comment: thank you so much  - works great :) I added the class to it's parent

Answer (score -1):

YOu're removing the class 'selected' from every element returned in linkClass every time you find an entry in arr that doesn't match your page title and adding it to every element when you do find one.

Try the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var nav=$('.menu_nav ul li a');
    var pageTitle = $('page_title').text();

    nav.removeClass('selected');
    nav.each(function(item) {
        if ($(item).text().toLowerCase() === pageTitle.toLowerCase())
            $(item).addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats great I don't need to push the items in the array here. Thank you